# Billy hearts some numbers

Tags: riddle

Billy likes the number 25 but not 35. He likes 144 but not 145. He likes 8100 but not 8000.

Does he like 872 or 841?

Comment: I edited the question and replaced "25 but not 25" with "25 but not 24" since it looked like a typo. Feel free to roll it back in case I did it wrong.

Comment: I actually put 25 but not 35.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 841

Because

> he likes perfect squares.
>  $841 = 29^2$

he likes 25 because

> $25 = 5^2$

He likes 144 because

> $144 = 12^2$

He likes 8100 becasue

> $8100 = 90^2$

Comment: This is only correct assuming the first line has a typo, and you probably shouldn't just edit someone's question like that

Comment: @GordonAllocman it was a typo. I've seen this problem before. Here is one similar: http://www.free-iqtest.net/answers.asp?q=15

Comment: This is a very well known puzzle.

Comment: Just because another similar question exists, doesn't mean it is exactly this one. While in all likelihood it was just a typo, you should really let OP fix it to be safe

Comment: I agree. I guess I got an adrenaline rush because I knew the answer. I guess the OP can roll it back if there is a problem and earn a badge for "first rollback".

Comment: Guys its okay if he corrects it

Comment: But I put 35 there on purpose.

Comment: @Xxoplechic You put 25 by mistake instead of 35 and I "corrected" it to 24. See initial post: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/posts/35054/revisions

Answer (score 1):

That was easy.
Billy likes

> 841.

Clearly because,

> Billy likes perfect squares. 841 is the square of 29.